# Angularjs - Multiply currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, currency

I'm trying to multiple a `value` x `months`.

In the input `value` i'm using this [Jquery Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) to do the currency mask.

But, the operations doesn't work with the plugin. I want to multiply the value, including cents.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z7AYk/)**

```
<div ng-app>
Months: <input type="text" ng-model="months"><br/>
Value:<input type="text" class="mony" ng-model="value"><br/>
Total: <input type="text" disabled="true" value="{{months*value | currency}}">
</div>
```

Comment: I've also noticed that the plugin/angular interaction is off. Check out the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7AYk/3/ Put in a large enough value for separators to be added and notice that the masked value and the bound value placements are off by a position. This means that even if you properly remove the 'thousands' separator and convert the 'fractional' separator, it still won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the value becomes formatted string that is not understood as a number.
So multiplication does not work.

In Angular it is discouraged to use jQuery to modify DOM, all modifications should be done from Directives.
So the best solution is to find the formater directive or create your own. Just search for something like "angularjs mask input".

Or maybe you can create controller and one of its methods will parse your string back into Number. If you still want to stick with jQuery without directive.